# laravel API in vue js

Tags: mysql, vue.js, vite

No data return in `EmployeeInfo.id` however there is a data array in `EmployeeInfo` and the requested data in API are all good. But when  put `<td>{{EmployeeInfo[0].id}}</td>` I get the value of `id=1`.

I want to display all the records in my table but unluckily no value return.

What is the problem in my code?

```
            <tr v-for="EmployeeInfo in EmployeeInfos" :key="EmployeeInfo.id">
                <td>{{ EmployeeInfo.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ EmployeeInfo.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ EmployeeInfo.lastname }}</td>

<script>
    export default {
        
        data() {
            return {
                EmployeeInfos: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.axios
                .get('http://localhost:8000/api/employee/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.EmployeeInfos = response.data;
                
                });
                
        },
</script>
```

Comment: verify if api returns array of employee and try yo put key :key="EmployeeInfo.id"

Comment: Try to check v-if before showing data

Comment: @RobertMihaiIonas yes the api returns array of string already and the key="EmployeeInfo.id" already change but still no data if i put {{EmployeeInfo.id}}. But if i put EmployeeInfo[0].id it return the value of id 1

Comment: try to change this to your correct response this.EmployeeInfos = response.data.data;